# Unity3D and Soomla, error in PostBuild processing

Tags: python, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, soomla

I'm trying to make build for iOS in Unity5. In my project I have Soomla plugin. And when build done, in console I can see error message.
That message says that there are problems in 31 line of Soomla_CoreRunner.py file and in 32 line of Soomla_StoreRunner.py file.
That lines have same line of code

```
pbx_object = XcodeProject.Load(pbx_file_path)
```

It seems like pbx_file_path is wrong. Here is how pbx_file_path is built

```
pbx_file_path = sys.argv[1] + '/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
```

So how to fix it? Why it gives error?

Comment: you might get quicker answers at the dedicated soomla forum answers.soom.la

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if this will fix your problem but it fixed probably the similar problem for me:

http://answers.soom.la/t/solved-errors-on-ios-with-unity-4-5-and-current-soomla-unitypackage/166/9